# Unable to create a constant value of type ' Program+NameId'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to fetch some records from db using entity framework 6 on the basis of another in memory complex type list nameIdList.

Here is my code,

```
var nameIdList = new List<NameId>()
{
    new NameId {Id= "425513E3-49F1-417B-A007-70B7BAA7D320",LastModified = "2017-06-22 14:59:14.917",  Name= "Name1" },
    new NameId {Id= "422FE343-A091-41CE-88E3-EEF427AC0F0E",LastModified = "2017-06-22 11:59:14.917",  Name= "Name2" },
};


var ids = nameIdList.Select(i => i.Id);
using (var modelContext= new Model1())
{
    var emps = modelContext.Employees.Where(e => ids.Contains(e.EmployeeId)
    && e.LastModified> nameIdList.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Id==e.EmployeeId).LastModified).ToList();

}
```

As entity framework does not support join with in-memory complex type list, is there any other work around for above scenario instead of using plane ADO.NET stored procedures. 
I don't want to use AsEnumerable() as there is large number of records in db which has serious performance impact.

I am using EF 6 and C# 4.5

Comment: There is no such thing as "join with in-memory complex type". LINQ to SQL didn't support this either - it loaded what it could from the database into memory, then joining everything in memory. This was actually a problem, not a feature - L2S loaded a lot more than it should, sometimes entire tables, without warning.

Comment: *What* do you want to load? What are the criteria? Load all employees whose ID is in a list and last modification is after a certain date? Where did that modification date come from? You already covered the `ID in a list` part with `ids.Contains`

Comment: If you want to find *changes* in the database, SQL Server already has a change tracking mechanism since 2005. Instead of tracking IDs and timestamps, you can ask for changed records since a version number. SQL Server will return the PKs of all inserted/updated/deleted records since that version number, with the reason (I,U,D) and optionally, the changed values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its in nameIdList . Criteria is get me the employees which has id in the list and that employ nelonging to that id has  lastmodifiedDate > LastModified date in nameIdList

Comment: And where does that date come from? The database itself? Another system? Last imported value? You could get all modified records with `CHANGETABLE(CHANGES EMPLOYEES, @last_synchronization_version)`. You could further filter the query by the primary key, ie ID. You may not need the timestamps at all

Comment: If you want to make all that in one query - you have to use raw queries or stored procedures

Comment: Its from users mobile device, via api call

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to make something like this work is to turn it into a stored procedure, and have a table valued parameter containing the data in the nameIdList. Stored procedures are not that hard to work with in EF so maybe it's an option.